# Google Plus login with Javascript and Authenticating with PHP

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth

While implementing the Facebook Connect to a web application , its possible to show Facebook Sign up page in a pop up and once logging in and Granting permissions  are complete, its possible to Authenticate Again in PHP and to get the necessary details of the user, - id, email etc.

I believe, thats secure because, the User Insertion is not based on the Ajax Request Parameters.

Is it possible to do the same with Google Plus Login also ?

Means - Logging in to Google - Using Javascript SDK, asking permissions, Authenticating all done in a Pop Up Window. and then, Creating a new user with the Help of google-api-php-client ??

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38094113/1153703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you're trying to do is outlined with https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow which includes some PHP code samples to help you do this. In general, the steps at authentication time are:

1. User clicks the "Sign in with Google" button which may pop-up a new window at Google prompting them to log in and authorize your webapp.
2. After they do so, a one-time code is sent to a JavaScript callback you specify.
3. Your Javascript method sends this code to your PHP server.
4. Your PHP server uses the client library to contact Google's server and exchange this one-time code for an access token and refresh token, which you keep and use to perform actions on the user's behalf.