# Google+ login via Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, google-plus, google-oauth, google-signin

Can you tell me please, how can I get user data(name, email) via Google+ Javascript/Php api? I go according this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), which describes how to get `authResult['code']` via Javascript.

Thats ok I have it. I send it to server via Ajax but I don't know how to get user data like name and email via PHP BUT without any redirects. Here are the samples of code
Javascript:

```
function googleStart()
{
    console.log('googleStart');
    gapi.load('auth2', function()
    {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '811214467813-v3fmui5dfghte5m0kmohsf6dl11ori3tg.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
            fetch_basic_profile: false,
            scope: 'profile email'
        });
    });
}

function googleSignIn(authResult)
{
    console.log(authResult);

    if (authResult['code']) {

        console.log(authResult);

        // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
        $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');

        // Send the code to the server
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : "{link :Signgoogle:in}",
            accepts : 'json',
            // Spýtať sa na DJPW čo to tu je zakomentované
            //contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
            //processData: false,
            data : {
                'code' : authResult['code'],
                'id_token' : authResult.getAuthResponse().id_token
            },
...
```

PHP:

```
public function actionIn()
{
    $code = $_POST['code'];

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(self::APP_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(self::APP_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri(self::REDIRECT_URI);

    $client->authenticate($code);
    $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
    $client->setAccessToken($access_token);

    $client->getAuth();


    $data = $access_token;

    if($data)
    {
        $this->sendJson(array($data));
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('error' => '$client->verifyIdToken($id) skočil chybou.');
        $this->sendJson($data);
    }

}
....
```

PHP retrieves an `access_token` but no users data. Ofcourse it is an ajax call so I can't do any redirects as Google describes on every page. Can you help me please I can't find any solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have an authenticated client for the user you will want to make a request to the [Google+ people.get API method](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get).

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$me = $plus->people->get('me');
print "ID: {$me['id']}\n";
print "Display Name: {$me['displayName']}\n";
print "Image Url: {$me['image']['url']}\n";
print "Url: {$me['url']}\n";
```

For their [email](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#emails) you will have to iterate over the `$me['emails']` array and find the value with `type=account`.

Comment: At first thank you. But where is $plus variable from? It is instance of what? I am not a witch.

Comment: I have found this code: $plus = new \Google_PlusService($client); but it throws exception: Class 'Google_PlusService' not found. I have instaled Google api via Composer: require: {"google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"}

Comment: It is insane!!! It seems the right form is $plus = new \Google_Service_Plus($client);

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed a couple of lines copying the code. I've updated the question with what should work.

Answer (score 6):

if you are not using google client library you can use this google api For getting the client details you just pass the token to this api https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token= < your_token >

```
$response = file_get_contents ( 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=' . $_REQUEST['token'] );

$response = json_decode ( $response );

echo "<pre>";
print_r ( $response );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will authenticate the user and it will return object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [iss] => accounts.google.com
    [at_hash] => hE0R********nxg
    [aud] => 79*********************p.apps.googleusercontent.com
    [sub] => 1028*****2
    [email_verified] => true
    [azp] => 7945823****p.apps.googleusercontent.com
    [email] => bik***@gmail.com
    [iat] => 14***7
    [exp] => 1***07
    [name] => Bik****M
    [picture] => https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-W8cA***/photo.jpg
    [given_name] => Bike***
    [family_name] => M
    [locale] => en
    [alg] => RS256
    [kid] => 70f6c4267*******cb
)
```

fount an example here : http://wiki.workassis.com/implementing-google-sign-in-for-websites